# SSIS features for staging table

Tags: ssis, staging

I am now working with SSIS in the stage of loading data from sources into our data warehouse staging. I am not sure that they are any kinds of features for controlling staging process e.g. control the working tables, write to logging tables, separate batches for the data, merge each batch together...

Right now we are using our own written store procedures to control these steps for staging. Can any of you give me suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1):

I typically use RAW files for staging, and many similar tasks. The link below has a nice summary.

http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/